# Inversing PCA transform with sklearn (with whiten=True)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pca

Usually PCA transform is easily inversed:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition

x = np.zeros((500, 10))
x[:, :5] = random.rand(500, 5)
x[:, 5:] = x[:, :5] # so that using PCA would make sense

p = decomposition.PCA()
p.fit(x)

a = x[5, :]

print p.inverse_transform(p.transform(a)) - a  # this yields small numbers (about 10**-16)
```

Now, if we try to add whiten=True parameter the result will be entirely different:

```
p = decomposition.PCA(whiten=True)
p.fit(x)

a = x[5, :]

print p.inverse_transform(p.transform(a)) - a  # now yields numbers about 10**15
```

So, as I didn't find any other methods that would do the trick, I wounder how is it possible to obtain the original value of a? Or is it even possible at all? Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This behaviour is admittedly potentially weird, but it is nevertheless documented in the docstrings of the relevant functions.

The class docstring of `PCA` says the following about `whiten`:

```
whiten : bool, optional
    When True (False by default) the `components_` vectors are divided
    by n_samples times singular values to ensure uncorrelated outputs
    with unit component-wise variances.

    Whitening will remove some information from the transformed signal
    (the relative variance scales of the components) but can sometime
    improve the predictive accuracy of the downstream estimators by
    making there data respect some hard-wired assumptions.
```

The code and docstring of `PCA.inverse_transform` says:

```
def inverse_transform(self, X):
    """Transform data back to its original space, i.e.,
    return an input X_original whose transform would be X

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_components)
        New data, where n_samples is the number of samples
        and n_components is the number of components.

    Returns
    -------
    X_original array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)

    Notes
    -----
    If whitening is enabled, inverse_transform does not compute the
    exact inverse operation as transform.
    """
    return np.dot(X, self.components_) + self.mean_
```

Now take a look at what happens when `whiten=True` in the function `PCA._fit`:

```
    if self.whiten:
        self.components_ = V / S[:, np.newaxis] * np.sqrt(n_samples)
    else:
        self.components_ = V
```

where `S` are singular values and `V` are singular vectors. By definition, whitening levels the spectrum, essentially setting all of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix to `1`.

In order to finally **answer your question**: The `PCA` object of sklearn.decomposition does not allow reconstructing original data from the whitened matrix, <s>because the singular values of the centered data / the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix are garbage collected after the function `PCA._fit`.</s>

**However**, if you obtain the singular values `S` manually, you will be able to multiply them back and arrive back at your original data.

Try this

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

n_samples_train, n_features = 40, 10
n_samples_test = 20
X_train = rng.randn(n_samples_train, n_features)
X_test = rng.randn(n_samples_test, n_features)

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(whiten=True)

pca.fit(X_train)

X_train_mean = X_train.mean(0)
X_train_centered = X_train - X_train_mean
U, S, VT = np.linalg.svd(X_train_centered, full_matrices=False)
components = VT / S[:, np.newaxis] * np.sqrt(n_samples_train)

from numpy.testing import assert_array_almost_equal
# These assertions will raise an error if the arrays aren't equal
assert_array_almost_equal(components, pca.components_)  # we have successfully 
                                                        # calculated whitened components

transformed = pca.transform(X_test)
inverse_transformed = transformed.dot(S[:, np.newaxis] ** 2 * pca.components_ /
                                            n_samples_train) + X_train_mean

assert_array_almost_equal(inverse_transformed, X_test)  # We have equality
```

As you can see from the line creating `inverse_transformed`, if you multiply the singular values back to the components, you can return to the original space.

As a matter of fact, the singular values `S` are actually hidden in the norms of the components, so there is no need to calculate an SVD along side the `PCA`. Using the definitions above one can see

```
S_recalculated = 1. / np.sqrt((pca.components_ ** 2).sum(axis=1) / n_samples_train)
assert_array_almost_equal(S, S_recalculated)
```

**Conclusion**: By obtaining the singular values of the centered data matrix, we are able to undo the whitening and transform back to the original space. However, this functionality is not natively implemented in the `PCA` object.

**Remedy**: *Without modifying the code of scikit learn* (which may be done officially if considered useful by the community), the solution you are looking for is this (and I will now use your code and variable names, please check if this works for you):

```
transformed_a = p.transform(a)
singular_values = 1. / np.sqrt((p.components_ ** 2).sum(axis=1) / len(x))
inverse_transformed = np.dot(transformed_a, singular_values[:, np.newaxis] ** 2 *
                                          p.components_ / len(x)) + p.mean_)
```

(IMHO the `inverse_transform` function of any estimator should go back a close as possible to the original data. In this case it would not cost much to also store the singular values explicitly, so maybe this functionality should actually be added to sklearn.)

**EDIT** The singular values of the centered matrix are not garbage collected as initially thought. As a matter of fact, they are stored in `pca.explained_variance_` and can be used to unwhiten. See comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked great. I used PCA previously with R, which was able to inverse the transformation whether components were rescaled to have unit variances or not, so I was pretty surprised to find sklearn unable to do so.

Comment: I am surprised as well. The fact that it is explicitly documented suggests that there is a reason behind it. If there isn't, I think it should be changed.

Comment: re-reading your comment, to be precise, whitening is not only transforrming components to have unit variance (this is easily done by `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` and is easily inverse transformed as well). It is a decorrelation in the gaussian sense: The covariance matrix of your whitened features will be diagonal

Comment: btw, there is no need to actually know the `len(x)` parameter (it is canceled out when calculating the `inverse_transformed`)  or to take the square root of `singular_values`, this works: `singular_values_sq = 1. / (p.components_ ** 2).sum(axis=1); inverse_transformed = np.dot(transformed_a, singular_values_sq[:, np.newaxis] * p.components_) + p.mean_`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that totally works, thanks for the comment. I was sticking blindly to what the code in `sklearn` did and then inverted it, without looking at what may cancel. You shouldn't call them `singular_values_sq` then, though, more something like `singular_values_squared_and_rescaled` (hope your editor has tab complete ;))

Comment: Well, I noticed the extra sqrt operation first, hence the name) Then started thinking that _theoretically_ `len(x)` should not be required to make the inverse transform.. And yeah, god bless tab complete :)

Comment: Update: The rescaled squared singular values are actually to be found in `pca.explained_variance_`, so no need to calculate these at all.

Comment: Oh, right, exactly! And that is where gigantic difference after `p.inverse_transform()` come from - the last 5 of `p.explained_variance_` are extremely close to 0 as there are only 5 actually independent coordinates in my `x` example.

Comment: Update: This has actually been fixed to do appropriate unwhitening on inverse transform if specified (>= 0.16)

Answer (score 4):

`self.components_` is originally Eignenvectors which subject to

```
>>> np.allclose(self.components_.T, np.linalg.inv(self.components_))
True
```

To project(`transform` in `sklearn`)  to these components, PCA **subtracts** their `self.mean_` and **multiplies** `self.components_` as

```
   Y = np.dot(X - self.mean_, self.components_.T) 
=> Y = (X - mean) * V.T # rewritten for simple notation
```

where `X` is the samples, `mean` is the mean of the training samples, and `V` is the principal components.

Then **the reconstruction**(`inverse_transform` in `sklearn`) is as follows (to get `Y` from `X`)

```
   Y = (X - mean) * V.T
=> Y*inv(V.T) = X - mean
=> Y*V = X - mean # inv(V.T) = V
=> X = Y*V + mean
=> Xrec = np.dot(X, self.components_) + self.mean_
```

---

The problem is `self.components_` of `whiten` PCA does not subject to

```
>>> np.allclose(self.components_.T, np.linalg.inv(self.components_))
False
```

You can derive the reason **why** from the code by @eickenberg.

So, you need to modify `sklearn.decomposition.pca`

1. the code retains `the reconstruction matrix`. `self.components_` of `whiten PCA` is

   ```
   self.components_ = V / S[:, np.newaxis] * np.sqrt(n_samples)
   ```

   So we can assign `the reconstruction matrix` as

   ```
   self.recons_ = V * S[:, np.newaxis] / np.sqrt(n_samples)
   ```
2. When `inverse_transform` is called, we will return the result derived by this matrix as

   ```
   if self.whiten:
       return np.dot(X, self.recons_) + self.mean_
   ```

That's it. Let's test.

```
>>> p = decomposition.PCA(whiten=True)
>>> p.fit(x)
>>> np.allclose(p.inverse_transform(p.transform(a)), a)
True
```

Sorry for my English. Please improve this post I am not sure theses expressions are correct.

Comment: The `PCA` object has a keyword argument `n_components`. If this is set, then your first condition will not render `True` (also in the SVD, the keyword `full_matrices=False` may lead to non square matrices). 

Your solution seems to add code to the scikit learn package. If you are interested, you should propose it to the community by means of a pull request to the [github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn). However, some changes may need to be made, since the way your code is right now, it copies the components, which is inefficient. Once removed, this can be interesting.

Comment: Looking at your post again, you should probably edit away the calls to invert the `components_` vector using `inv`, since it is not well defined in general. The pseudoinverse `pinv` will work in non square cases, but I am not sure whether the result is desired.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed now (version now is 0.24.2). But if you want to `inverse_transform` manually, here is the method:

```
pca = PCA()
reduced = pca.fit_transform(x)
x_original = np.dot(
    reduced / np.sqrt(n_samples-1) * pca.singular_values_,
    pca.components_
) + pca.mean_
```

As in the version now, `whiten=True` only affect the returned values of `fit` according to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed5584/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py#L386):

```
if self.whiten:
    # X_new = X * V / S * sqrt(n_samples) = U * sqrt(n_samples)
    U *= sqrt(X.shape[0] - 1)
else:
    # X_new = X * V = U * S * Vt * V = U * S
    U *= S[:self.n_components_]
```

In the sense, the document said that

> When True (False by default) the components_ vectors are multiplied by the square root of n_samples and then divided by the singular values to ensure uncorrelated outputs with unit component-wise variances.

is kind of misleading. The `components_` remains the same whatever the `whiten` argument is set to.